# I deployed a sp2010 wsp to sp2013, now SharePoint is looking in 15 hive for controltemplates

Tags: 2013, 2010, migration, solution-package

I have a SP2010 solution that I deployed to SP2013 (add-spsolution, install-spsolution).  The controltemplates installed to the 14 hive, but when I load a page in my site, I get an error that my controls can't be loaded.  When I look at the log files, I see that SharePoint is trying to locate them in the 15 hive.  How do I tell SharePoint to look in the 14 hive instead?

At this point, we don't want to recreate the 2010 solutions, just deploy them and get them working.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 3):

When I was working on new 2013 installs, we deployed files like those to both the 14 and 15 hives. Control Templates, images, etc. Sites created from 2010 templates looked in the 14 hive and sites created with 2013 templates looked in the 15 hives.

Comment: This is what @WOPR needs to do. The solution needs to be built for 14.5 mode Site Collections which means targeting 14,15.

Answer (score 0):

You can change where IIS looks for things pretty easily. Open the IIS config app, then drill down to your web app (expand the server, expand your site, expand the web application). Then you should see the _layouts folder. Under the Actions button, select "Basic Settings" and change the physical path from 15 to 14.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, my _controltemplates and _layouts path, under 'Basic Settings', are already set to 14 (C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\template\controltemplates)

Comment: This suggestion is also unsupported.